# np.where works 2 times like a charm - third time produces garbage

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting myself back into python again. Currently trying to learn some numpy stuff.
I have a numpy array `seq_arr` with 10x10 dimension and the numbers from 0 to 99.

```
seq_arr = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)
```

With this I want to set all odd numbers to zero, all numbers >17 to zero and finally everything %3==0 to zero. The first two things work:

```
even_arr = np.where(seq_arr % 2 == 0, seq_arr, 0)
bigger_than_arr = np.where(even_arr>17, seq_arr, 0)
```

After the last np.where I have:

```
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 18  0]
 [20  0 22  0 24  0 26  0 28  0]
 [30  0 32  0 34  0 36  0 38  0]
 [40  0 42  0 44  0 46  0 48  0]
 [50  0 52  0 54  0 56  0 58  0]
 [60  0 62  0 64  0 66  0 68  0]
 [70  0 72  0 74  0 76  0 78  0]
 [80  0 82  0 84  0 86  0 88  0]
 [90  0 92  0 94  0 96  0 98  0]]
```

Which is exatly what I want. After then applying my last condition

```
final_arr = np.where(bigger_than_arr%3==0, seq_arr, 0)
```

I only get a bunch of garbage:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
[ 0 21  0 23 24 25  0 27  0 29]
[30 31  0 33  0 35 36 37  0 39]
[ 0 41 42 43  0 45  0 47 48 49]
[ 0 51  0 53 54 55  0 57  0 59]
[60 61  0 63  0 65 66 67  0 69]
[ 0 71 72 73  0 75  0 77 78 79]
[ 0 81  0 83 84 85  0 87  0 89]
[90 91  0 93  0 95 96 97  0 99]]
```

Why to the odd numbers reappear? Why do the numbers <=17 reappear? I just don't get it.

Thanks!

doofesohr

Comment: Because 0%3 == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple here. You selected the wrong array in the second argument :)

```
final_arr = np.where(bigger_than_arr%3==0, bigger_than_arr, 0)
```

The stacking of the first two only works because odd numbers in the input array are all 0 and thus less than 17.

To be precise, the second condition should then of course be changed to the following:

```
bigger_than_arr = np.where(even_arr>17, even_arr, 0)
```

The overall output then looks like this:

```
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 18  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 24  0  0  0  0  0]
 [30  0  0  0  0  0 36  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 42  0  0  0  0  0 48  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 54  0  0  0  0  0]
 [60  0  0  0  0  0 66  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 72  0  0  0  0  0 78  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 84  0  0  0  0  0]
 [90  0  0  0  0  0 96  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: Thank you. The moment you wrote it, was the moment I found it. Sometimes writing it out here is the best way to find the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason the odd numbers and numbers <= 17 reappear is because 0 % 3 == 0.

Take for example index 1.

```
seq_arr[1] == 1
```

by the definition of np.arange

```
even_arr[1] <- seq_arr[1] if seq_arr[1] % 2 == 0, else 0.
even_arr[1] <- 1 if 1 % 2 == 0, else 0
even_arr[1] <- 0


bigger_than_arr[1] <- seq_arr[1] if even_arr[1] > 17, else 0
bigger_than_arr[1] <- 1 if 0 > 17, else 0
bigger_than_arr[1] <- 0


final_arr[1] <- seq_arr[1] if bigger_than_arr[1] % 3 == 0, else 0
final_arr[1] <- 1 if 0 % 3 == 0, else 0
(0 % 3 is == 0), therefore
final_arr[1] <- 1
```

What you may have intended was to write

```
final_arr = np.where(bigger_than_arr % 3 == 0, bigger_than_arr, 0)
```

Comment: The problem was rather using seq_arr for the true-condition of the where-function. This overwrote everything. Which worked in the 2nd step, but not in the third.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this sequence:

```
even_arr = np.where(seq_arr % 2 == 0, seq_arr, 0)
bigger_than_arr = np.where(even_arr>17, even_arr, 0)
final_arr = np.where(bigger_than_arr%3==0, bigger_than_arr, 0)
```

If you notice closely, the final result doesn't contain garbage. It contains all the values from your original array `seq_arr` where `bigger_than_arr` was zero. This is to be expected, since `0%3=0` and hence your condition is satisfied at all of those 'zeros'.